# Problems with the last element floating

Tags: html, css, floating

¿How i can solved this?
http://jsfiddle.net/Monobe/Yq7GK/

```
<div id="timeline">
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

The last element doesn't float correctly by the height of the previous element, how the bottom of the penultimate element not reached the bottom of the element in its left, the last element doesn't put correctly.

**I'm spanish, sorry if doesn't understand me, I have bad english...**

Comment: [how's this](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/Yq7GK/2/)

Comment: are you looking for `clear:left`?

Answer (score 0):

May it'll help you.

In table we have row just like that apply parent div.

```
<div id="timeline">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item">...</div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item">...</div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now apply css for class=row.

```
.row{float:left; width:100%; margin:5px 0;}
```